# Find the joint distribution of $Y_1$ and $Y_n$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, order-statistics

Let $X_1, \cdots , X_n$ be identically distributed random variables, with probability function $~ Exp (θ)$ with $θ = 1$.

Let $Y_1, \cdots, Y_n$ be the corresponding order statistics:

Obtain the joint density function of $Y_1$, and of $Y_n$, then show that $nY_n$ and $n(Y_2-Y_1)$ are independent

**What I have done:**

Remembering that for a random sample whose order statistics are $X_{(1)} \cdots X_{(n)}$

Then the joint pdf of $X_{(i)}$ and $X_{(j)}$ is:

$f_{X(i), X(j)} (u,v) = \dfrac{n!}{(i-1)! (j-1-i)! (n-j)!} f_{X}(u) f_{X}(v) [F_{X}(u)]^{i-1} \times [F_{X}(v) - F_{X}(u)]^{j-1-i} [1 - F_{X}(v)]^{n-j} $

Then

% \begin{align}

$f_{Y(i), Y(j)} (u,v) = \dfrac{n!}{(1-1)! (n-1-1)! (n-n)!} f_{X}(u) f_{X}(v) [F_{X}(u)]^{1-1} \times [F_{X}(v) - F_{X}(u)]^{n-1-1} [1 - F_{X}(v)]^{n-n} $

$ = \dfrac{n!}{(n-2)!} f_{X}(u) f_{X}(v) \times [F_{X}(v) - F_{X}(u)]^{n-2} $

% \end{align}